# ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint when adding database to mysql on ubuntu18.04

Tags: mysql-python

I am trying to add a database but when I create the tables I get the error 1215. After multiple google searches I have had no luck

```
mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
    ->         userid_pk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    ->         username VARCHAR(37) NOT NULL,
    ->         balance FLOAT NOT NULL,
    ->         PRIMARY KEY (username)
    ->         );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.04 sec)

mysql> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deposit (
    ->         userid_fk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
    ->         address_from VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
    ->         address_to VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
    ->         amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
    ->         FOREIGN KEY (userid_fk) REFERENCES person(userid_pk)
    ->         );
ERROR 1215 (HY000): Cannot add foreign key constraint
```

I tried googling it but that just confused me more lol

Here is the full DB I am trying to add, But I get the error mentioned above

```
def run():
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS person (
        userid_pk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
        username VARCHAR(37) NOT NULL,
        balance FLOAT NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (username)
        )""")
    '''
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS deposit (
        userid_fk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
        address_from VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        address_to VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (userid_fk) REFERENCES person(userid_pk)
        )""")

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS withdrawal (
        userid_fk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
        address_from VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        address_to VARCHAR(34) NOT NULL,
        amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (userid_fk) REFERENCES person(userid_pk)
        )""")

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tip (
        userid_from_fk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
        userid_to_fk VARCHAR(17) NOT NULL,
        amount FLOAT NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (userid_from_fk) REFERENCES person(userid_pk),
        FOREIGN KEY (userid_to_fk) REFERENCES person(userid_pk)
        )""")
    '''
    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS server (
        server_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        enable_soak TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
        PRIMARY KEY (server_id)
        )""")

    cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channel (
        channel_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        server_id VARCHAR(18) NOT NULL,
        enabled TINYINT(1) NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (server_id) REFERENCES server(server_id),
        PRIMARY KEY (channel_id)
        )""")
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated